# Mongoid Query sum of buffer_time an integer field + Time.now which is greater than scheduled_at field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a mongo model with buffer_time(Integer) and scheduled_at(DateTime) fields.
I want an optimised query to get

```
(Time.now + buffer_time.minutes) > scheduled_at
```

Here is the model AdministrationTask

```
{
                        :_id => BSON::ObjectId('53d5091870637330e84e0000'),
                :buffer_time => 60,
              :resident_name => "jegi",
               :scheduled_at => 2014-08-26 14:00:00 UTC,
                     :status => "open",
                 :updated_at => 2014-07-27 14:13:44 UTC
}
```

I can write this with map but it consume lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The CRUD operations only support simple comparisons and operations.
If you need to do calculations, the aggregation framework is recommended.
You should still consider simplifying your schema,
like eliminating the buffer_time field by incorporating its value into the value of scheduled_at.

The following is an answer showing how to use the aggregation framework to do what you want.
Hope that you like it and that it helps you understand how the aggregation framework can calculate results for matching.

test/unit/administration_task_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'pp'

class AdministrationTaskTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Mongoid.default_session.drop
  end
  test 'multiple tag references' do
    admin_task_data = {
        :buffer_time => 60,
        :resident_name => "jegi",
        :scheduled_at => Time.parse("2014-08-26 14:00:00 UTC"),
        :status => "open",
        :updated_at => Time.parse("2014-07-27 14:13:44 UTC")
    }
    AdministrationTask.create(admin_task_data)
    AdministrationTask.create(admin_task_data.merge(resident_name: 'xyzzy', scheduled_at: Time.now))
    puts "\nall administration tasks:"
    pp AdministrationTask.all.to_a
    run_now_tasks = AdministrationTask.collection.aggregate(
          {
              '$project' => {
                  '_id' => '$_id', 'buffer_time' => '$buffer_time', 'resident_name' => '$resident_name',
                    'scheduled_at' => '$scheduled_at', 'status' => '$status', 'updated_at' => '$updated_at',
                  'match' => {
                      '$gt' => [
                          {'$add' => [Time.now, {'$multiply' => ['$buffer_time', 1000]}]},
                          '$scheduled_at'
                      ]
                  }
              }
          },
          {
              '$match' => {'match' => true}
          }
      ).to_a
    puts "administration tasks to run now:"
    pp run_now_tasks
    assert_equal(1, run_now_tasks.size)
    assert_equal('xyzzy', run_now_tasks.first['resident_name'])
  end
  test '0. mongoid version' do
    puts "\nMongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
  end
end
```

rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/2] AdministrationTaskTest#test_0._mongoid_version
Mongoid::VERSION:3.1.6
Moped::VERSION:1.5.2
[2/2] AdministrationTaskTest#test_multiple_tag_references
all administration tasks:
[#<AdministrationTask _id: 53f266bd7f11ba0f51000001, buffer_time: 60, resident_name: "jegi", scheduled_at: 2014-08-26 14:00:00 UTC, status: "open", updated_at: 2014-07-27 14:13:44 UTC>,
 #<AdministrationTask _id: 53f266bd7f11ba0f51000002, buffer_time: 60, resident_name: "xyzzy", scheduled_at: 2014-08-18 20:49:01 UTC, status: "open", updated_at: 2014-07-27 14:13:44 UTC>]
administration tasks to run now:
[{"_id"=>"53f266bd7f11ba0f51000002",
  "buffer_time"=>60,
  "resident_name"=>"xyzzy",
  "scheduled_at"=>2014-08-18 20:49:01 UTC,
  "status"=>"open",
  "updated_at"=>2014-07-27 14:13:44 UTC,
  "match"=>true}]
Finished tests in 0.524457s, 3.8135 tests/s, 3.8135 assertions/s.
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```